# Rails - before_filter undefined local variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this form where a user input a review. A user must be signed with Facebook to save a review. 
I use a `before_filter` to check if the user is signed in or not.

But I get this error: `undefined local variable or method signed_in_user'`
.

The other thing is, how do I logged the user in with facebook and the save its review? Without losing and making the user input the same review again.

**Review form:**

```
<%= form_for [@school, Review.new] do |f| %>
 <%= f.text_area :content %>
    <% if current_user %>
      <%= f.submit 'Save my review', :class => "btn" %>
    <% else %>
      <%= f.submit 'Save my review and sign me into facebook', :class => "btn" %>
    <% end %>
<%end %>
```

**ReviewsController**

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

    def create
        @school = School.find(params[:school_id])
        @review = @school.reviews.new(params[:review])

        @review.user_id = current_user.id

        if @review.save
            redirect_to @review.school, notice: "Review has been created."
        else
            render :new
        end
    end

    def new
        @school = School.find_by_id(params[:school_id])
        @review = Review.new
    end
end
```

**ReviewsHelper**

```
module ReviewsHelper
    def signed_in?
        !current_user.nil?
    end

    def signed_in_user
        unless signed_in?   
            redirect_to "/auth/facebook"
        end
    end
end
```

I am using omniauth to authenticate users from facebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`include` your `ReviewsHelper` in controller:

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
    include ReviewsHelper #or helper :reviews
    before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

    def create
        @school = School.find(params[:school_id])
        @review = @school.reviews.new(params[:review])

        @review.user_id = current_user.id

        if @review.save
            redirect_to @review.school, notice: "Review has been created."
        else
            render :new
        end
    end

    def new
        @school = School.find_by_id(params[:school_id])
        @review = Review.new
    end
end
```

Comment: nice, but I am still losing the review data.

Comment: try `helper :reviews` in controller instead of `include`

Comment: if a user is unsigned and writes a review, then signs in with facebook they have to write the same review again. I would like to handle it more like this: unsigned user write a review, signs in with facebook and then the review is saved. But right now the user writes a review and then signs in and nothing is saved, the user have to write the review again.

Comment: For that you need to create `user_session` refer this http://railscasts.com/episodes/160-authlogic. It is for `authlogic` same can be implemented for omniauth

Answer (score 1):

Your helper is not included in the controller by default.

You can include it as codeit suggested.

Most people put their before filters in ApplicationController as a private method.

EDIT:

To persist the log in, save it to the session data.  Look up sessions in the Rails Guides.

Comment: thanks! Do you know how I can solve the losing data part? When the user logs in the have to input the review again.

Comment: I would have to disagree that "most people put before_filters in ApplicationController" as that is one of the least cohesive design decisions you could make. I usually see them as private methods in the same controller it pertains to, not the parent.

Comment: In C++ or Java I would agree.  However, private in ruby is for methods in the current class and inherited classes.

Comment: I guess the issue is if you always want helpers available in every controller.  In that case, putting them in the base class would make sense.  I see your point that this is a sloppy decision to always have all helpers available everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I have meet the same problem before. The helper is to help edit the view layer. The before_filter method cannot be written in the helper by default, unless you write 'include BlbalblaHelper' in the controller.

You Can just write the before_filter method in the application_controller.rb as a private method, or in lib/ folder. I think both of them are better approach for DRY.